# Copy nested ACF Flexible Content row from one page to another

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have two pages that are location for the same flexible content group. The group consists of a flexible content field that contains a repeater which contains another flexible content. And I want to copy a row from this last nested flexible content, to the corresponding flexible content in the other page.

Please see the attached image with the array representation for better understanding:

[image]

This is the code I have so far, but is not working.

With this function I get the fields structure:

```
function kb_update_elements_target($post_id, $flexibleContent) {

  $rows = array();
  
      if (have_rows($flexibleContent, $post_id)) {

          while (have_rows($flexibleContent, $post_id)) {
              
              $rows[] = the_row();

              if ( get_row_layout() == 'layout_hero' ) {

                if (have_rows('hero_row', $post_id)) {

                  while ( have_rows( 'hero_row', $post_id ) ) {

                    the_row();

                    if ( have_rows( 'hero_elements', $post_id ) ) {

                      while ( have_rows( 'hero_elements', $post_id ) ) {

                        the_row();

                        if ( get_row_layout() == 'heading_element' ) {

                          get_sub_field( 'heading', $post_id );

                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
      }
      return $rows;
  }
```

Then another function that is called through ajax get this data and updates the target page flexible content field:

```
$templateSection = kb_update_elements_target($sectionTemplateID, 'flexible_sections');

$pageContent = kb_update_elements_target($currentPageID, 'flexible_sections');

array_splice( $pageContent, 0, 0, $templateSection );

update_field( 'flexible_sections', $pageContent, $currentPageID );
```

But is not working, I can´t add the nested flexible content row in the Template into the corresponding field on the target page.
Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you.